# Accessing a method variable outside the method but in the same class

Tags: java

I have defined a method inside a class and inside that method I have initialized a string variable and initialized another string variable using replaceAll method to remove the vowels from the first string.How can I access the second string inside the main method of the same class?
Here is the code I have written:

```
public class removeVowels 
{
    public static String remV(String y)
    {
      String str="aebgreiouAfEOHNBI";
      String str1=str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","");
      return str1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: By calling the method and printing the result, not by trying to ignore variable scope.

Comment: Can you please show it?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class removeVowels 
{
    public static String remV(String y)
    {
        String stringMinusVowels=y.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","");
        return stringMinusVowels;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str1 = "Hello";
        String str1WithoutVowels = remV(str1);
        System.out.println(str1WithoutVowels);
    }
}
```

- Assumption 1: You want your method, remV to remove all vowels from a specified string
- Assumption 2: You want to print that string

Soultion: You want your make sure that your string, `str1` is within scope of your main method. This means that  it has to be declared either:

- within the brackets of your main method
- within the brackets of your class, but not within the brackets of another method within that class

Comment: The return type of `remV` should be a `String`, and why store the result of `replaceAll` for one line? You can use `(?i)` to make the regex case insensitive and just `return y.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "");` also, you forgot to actually rename `str1` to `myOldString` and I'm going to go ahead and mention that by convention the class name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Sorry about missing the return type and changing the name to str1/myOldString. The reason I didn't bother optimizing is because it is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your issue, it looks like you want to have your variable as a property of your class like this:

```
class removeVowels {
    static String str1;
    public static String remV(String y) {
        String str = "aebgreiouAfEOHNBI";
        str1 = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
        return str1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

Now, it might make more sense just to get the value of str1 from calling remV like this

```
class removeVowels {
    public static String remV(String y) {
        String str = "aebgreiouAfEOHNBI";
        String str1 = str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
        return str1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remV(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might make ***even* more** sense to pass `str` instead of `y` to the method.

Comment: How this last line of code works?If you can just explain .James Mcdowell

Answer (score 0):

```
public class removeVowels 

{ 
 static String str1 //declare static string
public static String remV(String y)
{
  String str="aebgreiouAfEOHNBI";
   str1=str.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","");
  return str1;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  remV("write anything"); //function is called so that str1 gets assigned
System.out.println(str1);
}
}
```